# Array treatment of multiple twig template blocks

Tags: php, twig

I have an odd situation where my twig template builds content to fit into several "boxes" such that the number of containing boxes can vary in number.  I'm looking for a general way of defining n blocks in the child template and the parent will render the right number.  Here is an example of what my child template looks like now:

```
{% extends "layout.participant.html.twig" %}

{% block box_left_title %}Personal Information{% endblock %}

{% block box_left_content %}
content here
{% endblock %}
```

Consider that there could be one, two or potentially 5 of these paired title/content sections.  What I'm imagining is some sort of way to define `box_left_title` as the first array slot and then the parent template (`layout.participant.html.twig`) would iterate each block and build as many "boxes" as necessary.

The workaround I'm considering right now is to define blocks of `box_left_content_1`, `box_left_content_2`, and so on in the parent template and then define only the ones used in the child.  While it will work it *feels* wrong.

Am I mis-using template inheritance here?  Should I instead look into conditional includes?  Pointers on this are most welcome.

**Update:** My question presumed that I could have dynamic blocks in the parent template, but this turns out to [not be possible](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/298).  I believe I'm going to need to define `block1`, `block2` etc in the parent (allowing for a reasonable upper limit) and then provide blocks with content in the children.  This is all assuming that includes aren't the preferred approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple approaches. The easiest though would probably be inclusion.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#including-other-templates

Say boxes is an array that looks like this:
    $boxes = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'First Title',
            'content' => 'the content of one',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Second Title',
            'content' => 'the content of two',
        ),
    );

You would use this in twig:

```
{% for box in boxes %}
    {% include "render_box.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now the render_box.html would run inside this for loop context, so the box vairable is present in this template. Your render_box.html would look like this:

```
<h1>{{ box.title }}</h1>

<p>{{ box.content }}</p>
```

Comment: This would work, but my concern is that the `content` portion of the array is going to be a load of html, much of it using twig variables and functions.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your approach is to fill in box.content twig code? That points for me to an error in your architecture. If you want to use templates, you don't want to put template code in some data... My example is oversimplified, you could enhance that with a million fields of course.